# home work question ,central limit theorem / law of large numbers

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

please reffer to this image , the entire question was tried earlier during an assignment , i have mentioned everything that i tried here in the image

[image: question]

Comment: What is the origin of the "$4$" and "$-4(2)$" terms in your calculation?

Comment: here $E ( X^2)$ = 2 so when we open the formula for $ (a-b)^2 $ we get the above result

Answer (score 2):

Let us calculate the 2nd and 4th moment. This seems to be where you are making a mistake.

$E(X^2) = Var(X)+E(X)^2 =\sigma^2 +\mu^2 = 1^2 + 1^2 = 2$

$E(X^4) = E(X)^4 +6E(X)^2Var(X) +3Var(X)^2 = 1 + 6 + 3 = 10$ (derive this as an exercise)

Now,
$Var(X^2) = E(X^4) -E(X^2)^2$

(using the well known variance formula of $Var(X) = E(X^2)-E(X)^2$)

$Var(X^2) = 10 -2^2 = 6$

Comment: but ( $E(X^4) $)  is    a   fourth    (even)    order    moment    from    normal distribution   and    should   be    given    by    $ 3(sd)^4$    , ( where sd is standard deviation ,) which comes    out    to    be    3    and    not  10 , ,

Comment: The $E(X^4)$ will be equals to 10. Will be $1+6+3=10$. I wrote down variance instead of standard deviation. My bad. But the final answer is still correct because of the unit variance.

Comment: but formula for even order  moments is $ \mu_2n $ = $\sigma^2$(2n-1)$\mu_2n-2$ , put n=2 , we get $\mu_4$ =3 , why is this incorrect ?